# How can I get scrapy to accept a page full of URLs as the start URL and just crawl those?

Tags: scrapy

So I have a page full of URLs that I'd like to crawl. 
As a newbie just following the tutorial, its quite hard to see how to expand the `start_urls` into grabbing all the links on that page. I'm guessing there's some way built in, but can't decipher the documentation very well. At the moment it just visits that top page, realizes that no, indeed, it isn't one of the child pages and raises some exception.

```
class NewSpider(Spider):
    name = 'the_new_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['newspider.com']
    start_urls = ['http://newspider.com/page_full_of_urls'] #how to get it to extract links from this page first and crawl them?

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        t = sel.xpath("//title")
        item = NewItem()
        item['title'] = t
        return item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html):

> In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return
>   either Item objects, Request objects, or an iterable of both. Those
>   Requests will also contain a callback (maybe the same) and will then
>   be downloaded by Scrapy and then their response handled by the
>   specified callback.

Something like this should work:

```
class NewSpider(Spider):
    name = 'the_new_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['newspider.com']
    start_urls = ['http://newspider.com/page_full_of_urls']

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        for url in sel.xpath("//.../@href").extract():
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_2)

    def parse_2(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        t = sel.xpath("//title")
        item = NewItem()
        item['title'] = t
        return item
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, the description just sounded very cryptic in the docs.